# React-native shadow not appearing

Tags: react-native, shadow

I'm trying to get a shadow below my views, and from what I found online it should be quite simple:

```html
shadowOffset: { width: 10, height: 10 },
shadowColor: 'black',
shadowOpacity: 1.0,
```

but the problem is that the shadow is not appearing at all.

Here's my components

```html
<View style={styles.shadow}>
    <View style={styles.box} >
        <View style={styles.ListComponent}>
            <Text style={styles.itemText}>Livestream</Text>
        </View>
    </View>
</View>
```

and in my StyleSheet:

```html
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    shadow: {
    shadowOffset: { width: 10, height: 10 },
    shadowColor: 'black',
    shadowOpacity: 1.0
},
```

Any reason for this or is there something I've missed?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Is the shadow working on IOs ?
Android and IOS work ≠ in React-Native. For android, it works with [elevation](https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping.html).

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
shadow: {
  shadowOffset: { width: 10, height: 10 },
  shadowColor: 'black',
  shadowOpacity: 1,
  elevation: 3,
  // background color must be set
  backgroundColor : "#0000" // invisible color
}
```

Otherwise, try to set a background color to your shadow component :)

Comment: I can't test on iOS at the moment so I'm not sure. Unfortunately elevation didn't work either. Not sure what you mean by adding a background color to the shadow component, wouldnt that just make the entire component that color, as its wrapping all components inside it?

Comment: [No background Color](https://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=677954Capturedecran20170704a165937.png) || 
[With background Color](https://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=320071Capturedecran20170704a170010.png)
You have to set a backgroundColor in order to enable the elevation. It will be the color of the entire <View>, but you can set another one for the subView :)

Comment: [Note that shadows won't appear if you have overflow:hidden set on the container](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/449)

Comment: @Eran thanks for the Tip. Removing the overflow: hidden makes the shadow to appear.

Comment: nice for the backgroudColor must be set

Comment: For elevation to work, I see that we need to provide either the `backgroundColor` or `borderWidth` (even setting borderWidth to 0 will work!).

Answer (score 20):

For iOS, raise the `zIndex` of your outer `<View>`

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({  
 shadow: {  
  shadowOffset: { width: 10, height: 10 },  
  shadowColor: 'black',  
  shadowOpacity: 1,  
  elevation: 3,  
  zIndex:999,  
}
```

Comment: I've been programming in iOS graphics for years, and may have an answer. Views clip at their border, so to get shadows to show, you usually have to use subviews, turn clipping off on the parent views that contain the shadows, but then keep clipping on for the views without shading. This is because the shadowRadius is outside clipping bounds. This was probably quite a challenge for the React Team, since it doesn't behave as desired, at least in my case. Should shadows ignore clipping or not, there's side-effects to both sides of that decision

Answer (score 17):

As some of the comments have pointed out, you're in a bit of a bind if you need `overflow: 'hidden'`.
(Such as for a card with rounded edges and a full-bleed image.)

A handy approach is to add shadow to a parent container with no `backgroundColor` set. That is due to this issue https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10049#issuecomment-366426897 which causes children to inherit the shadow of a parent view *without* a background. (It can look pretty weird when it affects multiple children.)

- Add a parent container with a shadow & no `backgroundColor` set.
- Have a single child view *with* a `backgroundColor`.

```
    <View // Parent
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        // No backgroundColor
        shadowColor: '#000',
        shadowOffset: {width: 0, height: 1},
        shadowOpacity: 0.8,
        shadowRadius: 2
      }}
    >
      <View // Card
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          borderRadius: 10,
          // To round image corners
          overflow: 'hidden',
          borderColor: '#999',
          borderWidth: 0.5,
          // https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10049#issuecomment-366426897
          backgroundColor: '#FFF',
          // Android shadow
          elevation: 4
        }}
      >
        <Image // Content
          style={{
            height: '50%',
            width: '100%',
            alignSelf: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center'
          }}
          source={{
            uri: 'https://yourimageurl.com/image.jpg'
          }}
          resizeMode="cover"
        />
      </View>
    </View>
```

[image: comparing shadow properties]

Answer (score 8):

I too wanted to have a shadow below my View in my Android app. So the trick I found was:

**For IOS:**

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    shadow: {
      shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
      shadowColor: '#000',
      shadowOpacity: 0.2
    }
});
```

**And For Android:**

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    shadow: {
        elevation: 5
    }
});
```

If you're working on UI elements I suggest you have a look at [NativeBase](https://nativebase.io/) site. They have made life easy as far as styling is concerned.

Answer (score 5):

I solved this by adding `overflow: 'visible'` to the style attributes of the `Image` I was applying the shadow to.

```
image: {
    overflow: 'visible',
    width: 300,
    height: 200,
    borderRadius: 4,
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOpacity: 0.2
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

Shadow works in React Native. All you have to do is Increase the Elevation to a higher value. And make sure there is no Hidden overflow on the parent container as it covers the extra part.
Here is the minimum code for Shadow render. It works perfectly fine as long as you have your Elevation value correct.

```
shadowColor: 'black',
shadowOpacity: 1,
elevation: 12,
```

Answer (score 1):

actually for me, it was `shodowOpacity` that was missing in my styles. I had given `shadowColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.4)'` and it was working on Android, I didn't know that I have to add also `shadowOpacity: 0.4` in order to work on iOS. adding it solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes changes do not take effect in react-native and you need to terminate the app and reopen it.
And also you have to save changes on every single file you have made.

Answer (score 0):

For Android, adding a `backgroundColor` to the container where you are applying the shadow, should work.
If your view is of `white` color by default, explicitly applying the `backgroundColor` to be `white` should bring in shadow on Android.

Answer (score -2):

**Solution for both borderRadius and shadow**

```
        <View style={{backgroundColor: '#000', ...shadow}}>
          <View style={{overflow: "hidden", borderRadius: 10}}>
            <VideoPlayer
                ...
                />
          </View>
        </View>
```

Comment: you fail to mention what is in shadow (...shadow) that you're destructring